# Punctuation Mark

Tags: punctuation

I just wanted to know the exact name of a punctuation mark which is used below a word or words to indicate the repetition i.e.

Impact of war on youth.
**//** //  // // elders.

What is the specific name for the punctuation mark which is below the words (Impact of war). Is it called double slash or double oblique hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

These are called *ditto marks*, and were traditionally represented by a quotation mark (") or a double prime mark ('').  In the modern era we have Unicode which has assigned the character U+3003 (〃) as the ditto mark for CJK scripts<sup>*</sup> and U+2033 (″) for western scripts.

- Chinese, Japanese, Korean